# OpenNESS Devkit for Azure: Permission Error

Tags: azure, devkit

I'm trying to follow the "OpenNESS Devkit for Azure" template that is shown on https://github.com/open-ness/openness-experience-kits/tree/master/cloud

When I try to deploy the template on Portal Azure, I get an error of this type:

`"The client '2a6fc298-c33a-4a3e-840e-d237ec92c777' with object id '2a6fc298-c33a-4a3e-840e-d237ec92c777' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/register/action' over scope '/subscriptions/53b81d7e-9278-4218-a658-9d7b3ae89c66' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}]}`

I assume it has something to do with this prerequisite: "Your account needs the Managed Identity Contributor role in order to create a user assigned managed identity".
But I already tried to assign this role to the Managed Identity that is being created and nothing changed.

For people who managed to deploy this template to Azure, what should I do to deal with this permission error?

Thank you

Comment: Try to grant the `User Access Administrator` role to the account.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me either